# Existe una función que aumente +1 a un array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo este formato:

```
[
  {"id":3,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false},
  {"id":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false},
  {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User Example 1","c":false}
]
```

Lo que quiero saber es que si existe alguna forma de poder poner +1 a cada id
es decir:

```
[
  {"id3":3,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false},
  {"id2":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false},
  {"id1":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User Example 1","c":false}
]
```

Comment: No lo hay, por lo que tienes que hacer una función propia para poder hacer lo que ocupas

Comment: Hola linux, como sería la funcion??, busqué información en google acerca de ello y no encontré....

Comment: @sioesi las propiedades `id` cambiaron a `id1, id2, id3`

Comment: Tienes que recorrer tu arreglo, obtener el valor de `id` de cada registro, y concatenarlo al nombre de la propiedad `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es reemplazar los objetos del array por nuevos objetos con las propiedades que te interesan:

```js
var foo = [
  {"id":3,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false},
  {"id":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false},
  {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User Example 1","c":false}
];

for (var el in foo){
  var newEl = {};
  var id = 'id' + foo[el].id;
  newEl[id] = foo[el].id;
  newEl['email'] = foo[el].email;
  newEl['name'] = foo[el].name;
  newEl['c'] = foo[el].c;
  foo[el] = newEl;
}

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias enseguida acepto la respuesta :)

Comment: En este caso estoy recibiendo desde aquí, como lo haría? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0l2xf16u9pfenh3/serial.js

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método getJSON de jQuery para cargar los datos en una variable (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)